# Message: Invalid argument. Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to debug this Google maps error.

Works in all tested browsers except IE. Sometimes markers show, sometimes they won't.

http://www.ecompanies.nl/pilot/warenhuis/breda.html

Webpage error details
Message: Invalid argument.
Line: 27
Char: 56
Code: 0
URI: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/nl_nl/mapfiles/api-3/5/6a/main.js

Comment: Are you still having a problem or has this been fixed at the site?  What version of IE?

Comment: do u solve this problem? i have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem, and for me, it turned out to be a conflict with a jquery ajax call on document.ready(). notable details:

- was including this gstatic file ref'd above
- was including jquery 1.6.4, in noConflict() mode
- was including jquery UI 1.8.14
- was executing an ajax call to populate a div (a cart widget, how many items, how much etc.), on document.ready()

to solve, i ended up with something like this:

```
// wrap ajax call in a function, then figure out if we execute it now, or delay.
var f = function(){
  $.getJSON('/ajax_handler/', function(data){/* do stuff */});
}
// check if google code is present (not sure how robust this is)
if(window['google']){ // We've got some Google, delay ajax call by 5s.
  setTimeout(f, 5000); // this was the lowest i could safely go, unfortunately.
} else { // No Google, do the ajax call immediately
  f();
}
```